# .ENV parsing issue (on Windows server)

Tags: craftcms

Has anyone had issues with Craft parsing a .env on Windows Server?   Dotenv is throwing an exception (FileException - invalid name) when parsing the first line of my .env, which is just a comment. I can remove that line and then i complains about the next line.

My .env simple starts with:

````
ENVIRONMENT=dev```

basically, Dotenv/Parser/isValidName's Regex call is  failing.
````